# Using the same POJO for a JPA entity and an Elasticsearch document

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have annotated a JPA entity both with `@Entity` and `@Document` (from Spring Data Elasticsearch) so I am basically indexing into Elasticsearch the same POJO as JPA.

Is this a good and recommended practice?

If not, what is the alternative? Having two distinct POJOs and mapping the JPA entity to the ES document using something like Dozer?

Comment: what approach did you go with? I am getting `No id property found for class` since the `@Id` is of type `javax.persistence` and elasticsearch looks for `@org.springframework.data.annotation.Id`.

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends on your use case and the complexity of your object model.  For a simple object model, I think that's fine.  For a more complex object model, there are a few things to think about:

- Do you really want/need to index all of the properties on the entity?
- Do you need to transform the object before indexing it?  For example, flattening relationships.
- Will the serialization to ES cause lazy relationships to be loaded when you don't want them to be loaded?

> If not, what is the alternative? Having two distinct POJOs and mapping
>   the JPA entity to the ES document using something like Dozer?

It looks like Spring Data Elasticsearch [is using Jackson for serialization](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/core/DefaultEntityMapper.java).  That's a pretty basic default configuration.  If that doesn't work for you and you don't want to introduce a DTO type object, you can always [implement your own mapper](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Custom-ObjectMapper).

Comment: Hi John. Thanks for the reply. There is still one thing I don't understand: do I have one mapper per index or per type?

Comment: Also, I realize I am definitely going to need a separate DTO/Elasticsearch Document. But how do you suggests I map the Jpa @Entity to the Elasticsearch @Document? Is using Dozer overkill?